# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this ajax json function where I use to send request and pull json response data (refer below)

```
//global array
var coaum_creation_date = [];
var coaum_arrears = [];
var coaum_wupdate= [];

var coaum_completed = [];
var coaum_pending = [];
var coaum_overdue = [];
//chart rendering
        function get_coaum_chart(){
            $.ajax({
               url: $("body").attr("data-link") + "/get-coaum-chart",
               type: 'post',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: { request : 'get coaum chart'},
               beforeSend: function(){

               },
               success: function(response){
                   if(response.success){
                       console.log(response);
                       //clear the array objects
                       coaum_creation_date = [];
                       coaum_arrears = [];
                       coaum_wupdate= [];

                       $.each(response.chart_data, function(index, value){
                           coaum_creation_date.push(value.creation_date);
                           coaum_arrears.push(parseInt(value.arrears));
                           coaum_wupdate.push(parseInt(value.with_updates));
                       });



                   }
               }
            });

        }
        get_coaum_chart();
```

and there is the json response along the error (refer to the image below)

[image: json response and the error]

any ideas, clues, recommendations, suggestions, help?

Comment: Don't put JSON strings in JSON.

Comment: Which line is line 226 of `coaum.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing here, but it can be because you can use `$.each` on Objects, but your `response.chart_data` seems to be a JSON string.
Try using `$.parseJSON()` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)):

`$.each($.parseJSON(response.chart_data), ...`

Hope it helps.

Comment: you can also use the pure javascript version which is :

``response.chart_data = JSON.parse(response.chart_data)``